# Vue component not immediately updating after associated data changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am still new to Vue and struggle with having a component update its contents as soon as connected data has been updated. The component will show the changed content as soon as it has been re-rendered though.

**Component**

```
Vue.component('report-summary', {
  props: ['translation', 'store'],
  watch: {
    'store.state.currentModel.Definition': {
      handler: function(change) {
        console.log('Change detected', change);
      },
      deep:true
    }
  },
  template: '<div>
    '<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">' +
    '<h5 class="border-bottom border-dark"> {{ translation.currently_defined }}</h5>' +
    '<div>{{ store.state.currentModel.Definition.length }} {{translation.elements }}</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
});
```

`store` is passed in as a property in the HTML of the page:

```
<report-summary :translation="t" :store="store"></report-summary>
```

`store` itself is a [Vuex.Store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/):

```
let store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    t: undefined,
    currentModel: undefined
  },
  mutations: {
    storeNewModel(state) {
      let model = CloneFactory.sealedClone(
        window.Project.Model.ReportTemplateModel);
      model.Header = CloneFactory.sealedClone(
        window.Project.Model.ReportTemplateHeaderModel);
      state.currentModel = model;
    },
    storeNewModelDefinition(state, definition) {
     state.currentModel.Definition.push(definition);
    }
  }
});
```

The `currentModel` element gets initialized by invoking `store.commit('storeNewModel');` before any data is stored in the model's `Definition` attribute.

The definition's content gets updated by using `store.commit('storeNewModelDefinition')` in a loop:

```
for (let c in this.$data.currentDefinition.charts) {
  store.commit('storeNewModelDefinition', c);
}
```

When `store.commit('storeNewModelDefinition', c);` is called the store updates as expected:

[image: Vuex%20Store|325x190]

But the component won't react to the changed data:

[image: Not%20updated|553x110]

Then when I navigate away (by changing the view which hides the embedded component) and again navigate to the view the content got updated:

[image: updated|476x112]

In the Console window I see that the watcher hasn't been triggered at any point in time:

[image: console|681x133]

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot for opening my eyes in advance.

### Using an EventBus

Switching the `watch` to an event bus listener also didn't work as planned.

This is the initialization of the EventBus:

```
window.eventBus= new Vue();
```

I added this to my Component:

```
  created: function() {
    window.eventBus.$on('report-summary-update', function() {
      this.$nextTick(function(){ this.$forceUpdate(); });
    });
  }
```

And emit the event after adding or removing elements from the list:

```
window.eventBus.$emit('report-summary-update');
```

When setting a breakpoint in the Debugger watching the `this.$forceUpdate();` I see that it's also being called but the UI still will show the old content without any changes. I am really lost right now.

---

*P.S. I cross-posted this on the [Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-component-not-immediately-updating/80939) but as the community is rather small hope to receive some feedback here.*

Comment: Just out of curiousity, any reason why you're not using `vue-cli` for this project?

Comment: Is there a reason you are passing the Vuex store in as a property instead of accessing it globally?

Comment: Has the object returned by `CloneFactory.sealedClone(window.Project.Model.ReportTemplateModel);` field `Definition` or are you creating it later ?

Comment: As said before I haven't really had the chance to do much with Vue so the `vue-cli` is also something I haven't used yet. Will check that out for sure! @MJ_Wales I tried accessing the store inside the template via `window.store...` but got an error instead that said that 'window is undefined'. Regarding the `ReportTemplateModel`, yes, that contains a property "Defitinition" which is an empty array when just initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing data to a nested array always causes such issues where the component does not update.

Try adding a getter to your store and use that getter to get data from the store

```
let store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    t: undefined,
    currentModel: undefined
  },
  mutations: {
    storeNewModel(state) {
      let model = CloneFactory.sealedClone(
        window.Project.Model.ReportTemplateModel);
      model.Header = CloneFactory.sealedClone(
        window.Project.Model.ReportTemplateHeaderModel);
      state.currentModel = model;
    },
    storeNewModelDefinition(state, definition) {
     state.currentModel.Definition.push(definition);
    }
  },
  getters:{
    definitions(state){
      return state.currentModel.Definition
    }
  }
});
```

In your component, you can add a computed prop that gets the data from store

```
Vue.component('report-summary', {
  props: ['translation', 'store'],
  computed: {
    definitions(){
     return store.getters.definitions
    }
  },
  template: '<div>
    '<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">' +
    '<h5 class="border-bottom border-dark"> {{ translation.currently_defined }}</h5>' +
    '<div>{{ definitions.length }} {{translation.elements }}</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
});
```

**UPDATE (30 Nov, 2019)**
If the above code still does not work, change your `storeNewModelDefinition` mutation to this:

```
storeNewModelDefinition(state, definition) {
     // Create a new copy of definitions
     let definitions = [...state.currentModel.Definition]

     // Push the new item
     definitions.push(definition)

     // Use `Vue.set` so that Vuejs reacts to the change
     Vue.set(state.currentModel, 'Definition', definitions);
    }
```

Comment: Just a typo, it should be definitions.length instead of definition.length (note the S)

Comment: I gave it a try, the getter and computer property were called when the component was initialized but not after a refresh to its underlying data happened. Still a helpful example, thanks for that.

Comment: @SaschaM78 
There was a typo in the `definitions` getter.`currentMode` was used instead of `currentModel`. I have fixed it now. I hope you fixed it in your code.
If it's still not working, then, I suggest one more change. Please see my update in the answer

Comment: Yes, I had seen this and had already changed it in my code. I will also test your updated code, thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

Just a note on your EventBus experiment (you should definitely try to fix the reactivity issue instead of trying tricks like `$forceUpdate`)

Reason why your experiment with EventBus didn't work is the use of *anonymous function* as an event handler. Take a look at this piece of code:

```js
  methods: {
    onEvent() {
      console.log(this)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // this.onEvent is method where "this" is bound to current Vue instance
    this.$bus.$on("test", this.onEvent);
    // Handler is anonymous function - "this" refers to EventBus Vue instance
    this.$bus.$on("test", function() {
      console.log(this)
    });
  }
```

- 1t event handler is a function where `this` is is explicitly (by Vue itself) bound to Vue instance where the handler "lives"
- 2nd event handler is anonymous function, `this` is not explicitly bound so it ends up like `this == event bus Vue instance`. You can work around that using closure like this:

```js
  mounted() {
    let self = this;
    this.$bus.$on("test", function() {
       // self = "this" in context of function "mounted"
       console.log(self)
    });
  }
```

`this` in JS can be tricky...

Comment: My old nemesis `this`. Yes, that perfectly makes sense that `this` does not refer to the Component in that case. I fixed my code to use the EventBus as shown in your example and now the Component gets updated as soon as the definition changes. I will still try to find a better way than to call `$forceUpdate` but for now it works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I disagree that event bus should be use to inform the component about changes in Vuex state. It's like using a gun to kill a mosquito. I request that this should not be marked as an accpeted answer as it could mislead upcoming developers in the community.

Comment: Completely agree. This shouldn't be an accepted answer. I was just trying to explain the problem with event bus code....

Comment: Michal, @AnkitKante, this answer solved my problem right now, that's why I had checked it as a solution. I unchecked it now and will go forward with the update you provided in your answer to see if I can fix my problem in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

From vuejs documentation Reactivity in depth section

> a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive

and this is one-off vue reactivity caveat. Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

in your state instead of `currentModel: undefined` add all properties you want to be reactive like

`currentModel: { definitions:[] }`

then any addition or removal of an element from `definitions` array would automatically become reactive.

And you can find more explanation on the documentation

[Reactivity in depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

[Change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the helpful links. I had already added an initial empty array `definitions` property in my tests but it still didn't fix the issue at that time (but it might be that I had additional issues in my code at that time that prevented it from working as expected).

Comment: Yes, adding new properties to objects already assigned to component data is problematic but if your component already has reactive property `currentModel` and you assign new object to it (as he did), whole object is made reactive. So its not important to define whole "shape" of your object in `data`. Your object just has to be "complete" (in regards to shape) __before__ you assign it into existing `data` property....